# Visual Studio: How to show Overloads in IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Once code has been written, the only way I know of to view the overloads for a method is to actually edit the method by deleting the Parenthesis `()` and reopening them.

Is there a shortcut key that I could press to activate this instead of having to edit my files?

For an example, please reference the **ShowDialog Overload** screen shot below:

[image: ShowDialog1 Overloads]

Comment: What ever happened to the good old up and down arrows?

Comment: @Zapnologica: The Up and Down arrows still exist, but the *IntelliSense* box needs to be activated and opened before those arrows can be used to scroll through the overload options. This question is about how to get the *IntelliSense* box to open.

Comment: How can you make it open by default,  control space vs control shift space

Comment: @Zapnologica: I use **Control + Shift + Space** sequence, like the old style **Control + Alt + Delete** combination.

Comment: In VS2012 it used to open by default when I typed an opened parenthesis after a function name, but it doesn't seem to do that anymore since I got ReSharper installed. Instead, it gives a dropdown menu of possible variables/functions to fill into the first arg. Quite annoying.

Comment: For people wondering where the nice auto up and down arrows went for overloads as you're typing: I'm not sure how long this option has been in VS settings but in VS Community 2019 v16.9.2 in Tools>Options>Text Editor>C#>IntelliSense there's a checkbox called 'Automatically show completion list in argument lists (experimental)'. If you uncheck that, the default behaviour of the up/down arrows scrolling through the overloads returns.

Answer (score 521, accepted):

With your cursor inside the parentheses, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>. If you changed the default, this corresponds to `Edit.ParameterInfo`.

### Example:

[image: descriptive screenshot, by jp2code]

Comment: At least in VS 2008, it seems that your cursor must be within the parentheses for this shortcut to work. Also, thanks for posting, I didn't know this existed!

Comment: Now if there was only a way to make this happen by default.

Comment: In VS2017 the cursed must be also within the parentheses.

Comment: In vscode this works too and you can use `Alt + Up` or `Alt + Down` to navigate between them.

Answer (score 67):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shows the `Edit.ParameterInfo` for the selected method, and by selected method I mean the caret must be within the method parentheses.

Here is the [Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13189).

And for those still using [2008](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7162).

Comment: Whoa, yours now looks way sexier than mine with your fancy keyboard tags! I can't let this happen!

Comment: +1, and another +1 for Neil if he would tell me how to do that on here.

Comment: For me on VS2017 this seems to be: Ctrl+Shift+Space, Space

Answer (score 67):

**Tested only on Visual Studio 2010.**

Place your cursor within the (), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then <kbd>P</kbd>.

Now navigate by pressing the  <kbd>↑</kbd>  / <kbd>↓</kbd>   arrow keys.

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but I can't get this to work in VS2008 or VS2010.

Comment: It's a VS2010 shortcut (not sure about 2008) - but it's possible you changed it or a tool you installed hijacked the shortcut.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Something simmilar to Ctrl+Q in IntelliJIdea/Android Studio.

Answer (score 25):

The default key binding for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
The underlying Visual Studio command is `Edit.ParameterInfo`.

If the standard keybinding doesn't work for you (possible in some profiles) then you can change it via the keyboard options page

- Tools -> Options
- Keyboard
- Type in Edit.ParameterInfo
- Change the shortcut key
- Hit Assign

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 if this  isn't working for you make sure you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31087682/68905  I had to do this to get it to work.

Answer (score 15):

It happens that none of the above methods work. Key binding is proper, but tool tip simply doesn't show in any case, neither as completion help or on demand.

To fix it just go to **Tools\Text Editor\C#** (or all languages) and check the '**Parameter Information**'. Now it should work

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Great question; I had the same issue. Turns out that there is indeed a keyboard shortcut to bring up this list: Ctrl+Shift+Space (a variation of the basic IntelliSense shortcut of Ctrl+Space).

Answer (score 6):

- The command `Edit.ParameterInfo` (mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by default) will show the overload tooltip if it's invoked when the cursor is inside the parameter brackets of a method call.
- The command `Edit.QuickInfo` (mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> by default) will show the tooltip that you'd see if you moused over the cursor location.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but for the newbies like myself who still hit this page this might be useful.
when you hover on a method you get a non clickable info-box whereas if you just write a comma in the method parenthesis the IntelliSense will offer you the beloved info-box with the clickable arrows.

Comment: that's not the same thing. That's the IntelliSense of what values you can put in. not the overloads window. For that you can just do Ctrl+Space

Answer (score 3):

Every once and a while the suggestions above stop working, if I restart Visual Studio they start working again though.

Answer (score 3):

you mean's change overload.
just Press Shift +  ↑  / ↓

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Mine showed up in VS2010 after writing the first parenthesis..

so, prams.Add(

After doings something like that, the box with the up and down arrows appeared.