# Visual Studio 2015 RC intellisense does not display parameter list

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

I have been using Visual Studio 2015 since CTP 6 and I have noticed that the IDE does not show the parameter list when I type the opening parenthesis "(".

This is what I am expecting to see:

[image]

In the screenshot above you see the the Create method has two overloads and this displays when I type the open parenthesis. But in Visual Studio CTP 6 and RC, nothing happens. I cannot see the overloads or the parameter list.

Is this a bug? Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's the answer: Go to Tools, Options, Text Editor, All Languages, General.  Then check the following options (override 'mixed' check):
- Auto list members
- Parameter information

Comment: This worked for me - just to reiterate - you have to get a 'tick' showing in the checkbox and not just a 'square' for this to work.

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Any ideas why this happens for some and not others?  I'm guessing it might have to do with me choosing to apply "C# developer" options and not "Web Developer" or some other options scheme when prompted by VS when it runs the first time.

Comment: Worked for me! This should be flagged as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was just a bug. I restarted Visual Studio and the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the shortcut for parameter info is `ctrl + shift + space` by default and in VS2015 RC it is working fine for me. May be it could be some user settings that might be overwriting default. You could see what the shortcut is by going at  Menu.Edit.IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the Method name, you get a tool tip with the method parameters. Maybe they thought this better?

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to suggested Go to Tools, Options, Text Editor, All Languages, General - and UN-check "Hide advanced members" check box under checked-on "Auto List Members." Then when I would type ( after class name it would show me all possible signatures in Intellisense. Hope it helps some.