# Visual Studio: Show all method overloads at once

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, is it possible to view all method overloads **at once**, so without having to cycle through them via the cursor keys?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio: How to show Overloads in IntelliSense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891656/visual-studio-how-to-show-overloads-in-intellisense)

Comment: unfortuantely not, as this does not show the overlaods at once, but instead one has to cycle through.

Comment: I'm sorry that Visual Studio's smart hints about overloaded functions only support looping, and there is no way to display all of them at once in the smart hints.
But at present, there is still a method to display all overloaded functions in other aspects, which is helpful to work efficiency when there are many overloaded functions.
You can use the search function of Visual Studio, ctrl+f to enter the overloaded function you want to find. Then click Find All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View - Object Explorer works quite well for this, though not integrated with IntelliSense:
[image]